# 127.0.0.1 as referrer url

Tags: url, referrer, localhost, windows

I have written some code to my website that shows some information about online users to admin user. one of these information was the host of referrer url of the user. I saw some 127.0.0.1 in the referrer url so I edited my code to show the full referrer url. I catch one:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/component/2?hash=d198c031431a77b616d9e5ba84214a4e
```

Can anybody tell me what is this? how this possible? is there a security issue?

PS: My website is running on my own dedicated server running windows server 2012.

**Update:** These are some of the ips and all have the same referrer url as about with different hash as querystring:

```
141.0.9.213
141.0.13.7
141.0.13.43
141.0.8.162
```

Comment: Make sure that this is something you have done in your app by using it yourself and carefully pay attention to the time and comparing what you see in your server logs. If it is not showing up when you use your app, then it is likely a spoofed referrer which is generally unreliable data since referrers are often spoofed. Spoofing the referrer data is easy to do.

Comment: Is there a process running on the same server that is accessing the website?

Comment: @closetnoc I'm sure its not something by myself (I have written the whole code no plugins, cms, ...) and by the way none of the have visited more than a page but same user with same ip visited several times during the day

Comment: @Mike there is no process accessing file that's why they look suspicious to me.

Comment: It is likely just a junk reference then. These things happen from time to time. Something to keep an eye on. You can always block them if it gets too annoying. We may be able to help with that when you get that far.

Comment: Where are you seeing the referrer server logs or Google Analylics?

Comment: I have written the code, I'm just showing the `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`

Comment: All those IPs belong to Opera ("Opera Software ASA" and "Opera Mini Servers").